# How to listen for browser closing events

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to make an ajax before the browser closes the window, but I'm having some trouble
The `beforeunload` event fires on both close and refresh and is not fired in the latest Chrome browsers if the user does not take action on the page.
How can I tell the user to close the window instead of refreshing?

My English is not good, Thanks for understanding

This does not work

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
  editPageUnLockApi(designId);
});
```

Comment: What do you need it for? Basically: there’s no *reliable* way for this. You probably need to rethink why you need this.

Comment: How about you do it over way around: ping every N seconds back-end that user is online. Back-end cron runs every few minutes to do the same `editPageUnLockApi` for users that does not ping for more than 2N seconds.

Comment: @Justinas what is `editPageUnLockApi`? Any links?

Comment: @vanowm Seems to be OP defined function

Comment: See https://github.com/WICG/pending-beacon/blob/main/docs/fetch-later-api.md